# Using pyserial ser.read results have a \r appended

Tags: python, pyserial

The following is to get the 1-wire serial number for a DS18B20 connected to a HA7E 1-wire adapter. ASCII "S" is the code to get the serial number.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.USA19H1d2P1.1",9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1,timeout=0)
ser.write("S")
ser.read(64)
```

The result of running the above gives '69000001CFD7E328\r'

Is there a way to stop the \r appending?

Answer (score 2):

You probably should consider the '\r' to be part of the protocol with the device. The question then becomes: "how do I discard protocol junk that I'm not interested in which is at the end of a string?"

The answer to that is easy:

```
raw_serial = ser.read(64)
serial_number = string.rstrip(raw_serial, '\r')
```

Comment: Wouldn't using a `str` method be better? `serial_number = raw_serial.rstrip("\r")` or even `serial_number = raw_serial.strip()` since `\r` is whitespace and who wants whitespace in serial numbers?

Comment: Without more complete information on what the device is going to emit, it is better to strip what is known to be unwanted (it probably doesn't matter, but we don't know). string.rstrip('s\r', '\r') is equivalent to  's\r'.rstrip('\r'), the former is more explicit at least for explanatory purposes here.